# Copy Failed during post-build process

Tags: visual-studio-2008, post-build-event

I am writing an ASP.NET web application using Visual Studio 2008.
The project is mostly unchanged from the default empty project that Visual Studio provides, except for:

- In Properties->Build->Output, "XML documentation file" is checked and set to "bin\MyProject.XML"
- In Properties->Build Events, "Post-build event command line:" is set to `copy /y "$(TargetDir)$(TargetName).XML" "C:\TEMP\"`

When I build the project for the first time, or rebuild, the build process completes successfully.
If I try to build any time after that, however, the build process fails with this message:

```
------ Build started: Project: MyProject, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
MyProject -> C:\Projects\MyProject\MyProject\bin\MyProject.dll
copy /y "C:\Projects\MyProject\MyProject\bin\MyProject.XML" "C:\TEMP\"
The system cannot find the file specified.
c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\Microsoft.Common.targets(3397,13): error MSB3073: The command "copy /y "C:\Projects\MyProject\MyProject\bin\MyProject.XML" "C:\TEMP\"" exited with code 1.
Done building project "MyProject.csproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded or up-to-date, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

I'm certain that the syntax is correct, because I can perform the post-build command in a command window:

```
C:\>copy /y "C:\Projects\MyProject\MyProject\bin\MyProject.XML" "C:\TEMP\"
        1 file(s) copied.
```

The command works when I do it manually, so why does it fail when it is part of the build process?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a flaw in the underlying msbuild tasks that are used by Visual Studio when the XML documentation file is generated in the same directory as the one specified as the *output path*, for intermediary builds.

To fix it, you need to specify a different directory, for example, like this:

[image]

and change your post-build copy command accordingly, like this:

```
copy /y "C:\Projects\MyProject\MyProject\docbin\Debug\MyProject.XML" "C:\TEMP\"
```

Comment: Thanks, you solved my problem! You also gave me sufficient information to find other people with the same problem as me. [Here on Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136400/visual-studio-incremental-build-xml-documentation-file-is-created-too-late), and on Visual Studio's [Feedback site](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/470485/strange-file-not-found-error-xml-documentation-file-renamed-during-incremental-build#details).